# What is the best way to load test SharePoint Online Search Rest API Calls?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-search, load-testing

I use SP Editor to test my search query performance but it does not give me consistent results. It is difficult to run multiple queries and get an average query run time.

Is there a way or a tool to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a load testing tool, there are multiple options like:

- [Gatling](https://gatling.io/)
- [Locust](https://locust.io/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/)
- It might also be the case your version of Visual Studio still has [load testing capabilities](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/testingspot-blog/guide-to-get-started-with-visual-studio-web-load-testing-and/ba-p/367582)

The latter one might be the easiest to use because Sharepoint in the majority of installations relies on [Windows Authentication mechanisms](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-jmeter) like [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) or [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) and JMeter provides [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) which simplifies configuration related to impersonating a Windows domain user.